# how prove $\sum_{i=1}^{k}|n_i-m_i|$ is even such that $m_1$,$m_2$,...,$m_k$ is permutation of $n_1$,$n_2$ ,...,$n_k$?

Tags: combinatorics

let $n_1$,$n_2$ ,...,$n_k$ be arbitrary integer and $m_1$,$m_2$,...,$m_k$ is

permutation of $n_1$,$n_2$ ,...,$n_k$ how prove $$|n_1-m_1|+|n_2-m_2|+|n_3-
m_3|+...+|n_k-m_k|$$ is even numbers ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you prove this if the absolute value signs are removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we know that $m$ is even iff  $({-1})^m=1(II)$ and ${(-1)}^n={(-1)}^{-n} (I)$so

$(-1)^{|n_1-m_1|+|n_2-m_2|+|n_3-m_3|+...+|n_k-m_k|} =$

$(-1)^{|n_1-m_1|} . (-1)^{|n_2-m_2|}... (-1)^{|n_k-m_k|}$ we have by attention to $(I)$ :

$(-1)^{n_1-m_1} . (-1)^{n_2-m_2}... (-1)^{n_k-m_k}=$

$(-1)^{(n_1-m_1)+(n_2-m_2)+(n_3-m_3)+...+(n_k-m_k)}$ but $\{m_1,...,m_k\}=\{n_1,...,n_k\} $so

$(-1)^0=1$ so proof is complete by attention to $(II)$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $\sum_{i=1}^k(n_i-m_i)$, without the absolute values, is obviously even; why? Now show and use the fact that if $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $a+b$ is even if and only if $a-b$ is even.